# Why is Gradle does not able to find the publish task on CI when it does so locally?

Tags: android, gradle, maven-publish

I have an Android library project that looks like this:

```
my-project
├── build.gradle.kts <- project level gradle file
├── gradle
│   └── wrapper
│       ├── gradle-wrapper.jar
│       └── gradle-wrapper.properties
├── gradle.properties
├── gradlew
├── lib
│   ├── build.gradle.kts <- module level gradle file
│   └── src
└── settings.gradle.kts
```

In the module level gradle file `lib/build.gradle.kts` I apply the `maven-publish` plugin and define a publication for the library. It looks something like this (omitting the irrelevant parts):

```kotlin
plugins {
    // ...
    id("maven-publish")
}
android {
    //...
    publishing {
        singleVariant("release") {
            withSourcesJar()
        }
    }
}
val libraryVersion: String by project
publishing {
    repositories {
        maven {
            name = // ...
            url = // ...
        }
    }
    publications {
        create<MavenPublication>("maven") {
            groupId = // ...
            artifactId = // ...
            version = libraryVersion
            afterEvaluate {
                from(components["release"])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On my machine running macOS 13.2 I can then run `./gradlew publish` and everything works as expected. However, on a GitHub actions runner (both on `ubuntu-latest` as well as `macos-latest`) when trying to run the `publish` task which shoul dbe generated by the [Maven Publish plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html#publishing_maven:tasks), I always get the following error:

```
Task 'publish' not found in root project 'bindings-android'.
```

Similarly when trying to run the task directly in the `lib` module (`:lib:publish`), I get:

```
Task 'publish' not found in project ':lib'.
```

The relevant part of the GitHub workflow look like this:

```yaml
# ...

jobs:
  publish-android:
    runs-on: macos-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          ref: ${{ inputs.version }}
      - name: Setup Java
        uses: actions/setup-java@v3
        with:
          distribution: temurin
          java-version: 11
      - name: Setup Gradle
        uses: gradle/gradle-build-action@v2
        with:
          gradle-version: 7.3.2
      - name: Publish artifacts
        uses: gradle/gradle-build-action@v2
        with:
          arguments: publish -PlibraryVersion=${{ inputs.version }}
```